# android ListView Simple Adapter, item repeating

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview, hashmap, simpleadapter

I created a custom `ListView` and in java filled that `ListView` with a `SimpleAdapter`. Here's my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);

itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    itemMap.put("song", songs[i]);
    itemMap.put("artist", artists[i]);
    System.out.println(songs[i] + "     " + artists[i]);
    itemList.add(itemMap);
}

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, itemList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"song",
                    "artist"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1,
                    android.R.id.text2 });
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I created two `String Arrays` Song and Artist respectively and put them in a `HashMap` and then put the `HashMap` in a `ArrayList` called `itemList`. After that i set up the adapter with the default list item id's in the parameter.

The problem I am facing is that when i run the application, the list view shows only the last item and subItem of the String Arrays repeatedly. Here's the image for reference.
[My ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4TYl.png)

I'd like to know why this is happening. I tried putting the `itemList.add(itemMap);` outside the `for()` loop but it still didn't work. Help would really be appreciated with a proper explanation, cause i'm kinda new to this. Thank You!

Comment: You are adding same key to the `HashMap` over and over.

Comment: uhhh a little elaboration would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by recreating your `itemMap` object at every iteration. Try the following way.

```
itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    itemMap.put("song", songs[i]);
    itemMap.put("artist", artists[i]);
    System.out.println(songs[i] + "     " + artists[i]);
    itemList.add(itemMap);
}
```

Change this to

```
for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    itemMap.put("song", songs[i]);
    itemMap.put("artist", artists[i]);
    System.out.println(songs[i] + "     " + artists[i]);
    itemList.add(itemMap);
}
```

Explaination:

[Refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) here. Note `HashMap` is a `key` `value` pair which means it will store some value for a key. So `HashMap` will not allow duplicate key. From your code already youe have added the value for `song` and `artist`. So you can not add the value for these keys again. But the `itemlist` add the `itemMap` at every iteration. That is why the list repeating the same record. To avoid this problem simply re instantiate the `itemMap` object.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Alright! It worked. Could you please explain why this worked? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

bro, you won't believe but you are doing wrong.

make a new object of HashMap on each iteration.

Comment: Yes I was doing it wrong, and apparently I found the solution to my problem, in July 2013. Bro, you won't believe but you're 9 months too late.

Comment: I believe you my friend.. I didn't see the post date.. :D :P ;)