# ListView item repeating when adding new item

Tags: android, repeat, simpleadapter

Whenever i add a new item in my **ListView** shows only the last item repeatedly

```
 final ArrayList<Map<String, String>> persontList = new ArrayList <Map<String, String>>();

    ajout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

         Map<String, String> data;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nom = etname.getText().toString();
            String number = etnumber.getText().toString();
            Person p =new Person(nom, number);
            String strNumber = String.valueOf(p.getPhoneNumber());
            data =  new HashMap<String, String>(2);
            data.put("FullName",p.getFullName());
            data.put("PhoneNumber",strNumber);

            persontList.add(data);
            SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, persontList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{"FullName", "PhoneNumber"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
            lvStudent.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }
    });
```

i saw this [android ListView Simple Adapter, item repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714580/android-listview-simple-adapter-item-repeating), but it dosen't seem to work for me

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's directly related to your problem, but you should not be doing:

```
SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, persontList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{"FullName", "PhoneNumber"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
lvStudent.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

It's not mandatory, but probably you don't want to create a simple adapter every time you click your View.

Try creating your adapter out of this callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you create a SimpleAdapter every time you click on "ajout".

You have just to add the item to the list to the adapter that you had created before the click event.

For example:

```
final ArrayList<Map<String, String>> persontList = new ArrayList <Map<String, String>>();
SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, persontList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{"FullName", "PhoneNumber"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

    ajout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

         Map<String, String> data;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nom = etname.getText().toString();
            String number = etnumber.getText().toString();
            Person p =new Person(nom, number);
            String strNumber = String.valueOf(p.getPhoneNumber());
            data =  new HashMap<String, String>(2);
            data.put("FullName",p.getFullName());
            data.put("PhoneNumber",strNumber);

            persontList.add(data);
            arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, persontList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{nom, number}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

            lvStudent.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        lvStudent.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `personlist.clear();` before `String nom = etname.getText().toString();`